# jQuery AJAX works to return mvc 3 partial view but jQuery load doesn't

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, load

I'm trying to populate a div with a partial view in MVC 3.  My controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetCustomerList(string searchString)
{
    var custService = new CustomerViewModels();
    var custListVM = custService.GetSearchList(searchString);

    return PartialView("GetCustomersList", custListVM);
}
```

and my jQuery call looks like this:

```
function getCustomerList(searchCriteria) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/GetCustomerList',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: { searchString: searchCriteria },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#customerTabBody").html(result);
        }
    });
};
```

It works fine.  I began to wonder if I could use the jQuery load method to do the same thing with a lot less code and wrote this:

```
function getCustomerList(searchCriteria) {
    $("#customerTabBody").load('Home/GetCustomerList', { searchString: searchCriteria });
};
```

It returns an error saying the resource can't be found.  I've tried using @Url.Action but it encodes the same controller path I have hard coded.  In Firebug I can see that the URL that is being posted to is the same and the searchString parameter is identically formatted in both instances.

What's the difference - why does load not work?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you setting async: false in the $.ajax call?

Comment: I need to keep the user from continuing to type in characters while I await the response.

Answer (score 2):

Jquery docs for [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) says...

```
The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.
```

since you are passing data as an object, it has to be a post call according to docs. Furthermore, you are getting required data from controller through $.ajax so controller action method seems to be alright. There may be some error when sending the ajax request using load. you can inspect this in firebug.

Comment: I've used Firebog to look carefully at the post data and the target controller URL is identical in both and so is the searchString key, value pair.

Comment: check the response of ajax request in firebug

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this to see if it works?

```
function getCustomerList(searchCriteria) {

         $('#customerTabBody').load('@Url.Action("GetCustomerList", "Home")', { 'searchString': searchCriteria });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain your [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) call executes a GET request rather than a POST. MVC 3 and most other .NET AJAX transactions (methods decorated as a WebMethod, such as web services and page methods) require data to be POSTed. In this case you'll simply need to stick with what works. As you can see in your working $.ajax() call, the request method is a POST. If you want to short-hand some of the code, use [.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) combined with [.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: asp.net mvc controller action methods do not require each ajax request to be post unless they are decorated with `HttpPost`. The only exception is the methods that return json result. even in that case you can allow `Get` requests like `return Json(data,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: Actually I wondered about that too.  I tried decorating my controller method with [HttpGet] but it still couldn't even find the resource so I don't think it mattered.  I also took at look at the post and response traffic in Firebug and it shows the postback generated by the jQuery load and it is displayed as a post (not a get).