# ASP.NET MVC3 passing one piece of data through a jquery ajax post to an MVC action

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to pass data to an MVC post action that is expecting 1 integer parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeactivateDepartment(int departmentId)
{
    return Json(new
        {
            success = _departmentsRepository.ToggleDepartmentState(departmentId, false)
        });
}
```

The jquery that I'm trying to utilize to hit this action looks like this...

```
var departmentId = 1;
$.ajax({
    url: '/Manage/DeactivateDepartment',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    data: departmentId
});
```

When I take the parameter off of the Action method and remove the data attribute from the jquery ajax object I am successfully able to hit the action method.  However, with the action methhod and ajax object as they are shown here I am getting an internal server error.

I've been looking at this post.
[jQuery AJAX works to return mvc 3 partial view but jQuery load doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811625/jquery-ajax-works-to-return-mvc-3-partial-view-but-jquery-load-doesnt)

It shows how to pass a json object that would be deserialized as an object when it hit the action method, but I don't want to have to create a custom class just to receive this one integer value that I'm trying to pass to the method.  How can I configure this thing to just accept the one value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var departmentId = 1; 
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/Manage/DeactivateDepartment', 
    type: 'POST', 
    success: function (data) { 
        alert(data); 
    }, 
    data: {departmentId:  departmentId } 
});
```

Comment: Wherever we use dataType: 'json', we also have to set traditional: true.